# ASP.NET Core: Dependencies: Latest Versions

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

I'm working with ASP.NET Core in VS Code. The project.json file contains many dependencies. For example:

```
"Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final"
```

The question I have is: how do I keep all my dependencies up-to-date with the latest versions? Also, it would be useful to know if there's some sort of wildcard or flag so that for any dependency, the latest final version is always used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually do a wildcard. For instance you could do:

```
"Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-*"
```

to get latest rc1 or even

```
"Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-*"
```

to get latest 6.0.0.

However if you do that you need to be aware of changes that are happening in the stack because you might start adopting newer versions unknowingly - as soon as new packages show up on NuGet/MyGet and you restore packages in your project (this is a bit less of a problem if you are using released bits that do not change often vs. nightly builds that change frequently and still have a lot of breaking changes).

Since ASP.Net Core has not reached v1 yet you still need to be aware of what's going on because even official pre-release versions still contain breaking changes. For instance in rc2 release packages will be renamed to contain `.AspNetCore.` instead of `.AspNet.` and the versions will be aligned to `1.0.0` (see [this](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/144) announcement for more details). From that perspective using `*` in your version names would have no effect because there won't be a newer version of `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc` than `6.0.0-rc1-final`.

I would recommend tracking the [Announcements](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements) repo to stay up-to-date with breaking changes.

Comment: Good points and useful information, thanks! It seems like I can also check the NuGet website to see specifically the version history of certain packages. Ex: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc/

Comment: Kind of but if the name of the package changes I think it will be on its own page...